# Sorting function not working (string comparison issue)

Tags: c++, sorting, char, wchar

I've got a sorting function which should put all usernames starting from 3 character or more to the top of the array, and all the ones under 3

```
if(wcslen((WCHAR*)playerNames[i]) < 3)
```

(Which will all be "-") to the bottom and replaced with `<Unknown>`. I've tried the following but I sets weird debugger values when replacing `"-"` with `"<Unknown>"` and crashes.

```
char* playerNames[30] = { "Player1", "Player2", "Player3", "Player4", "Player5", "Player6", "-", "Player7", "-", "-", "-", "-", "Player8", "Player9", "Player10", "Player11", "Player12", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "Player14", "Player15" };
void sort(){
    char* sorted[29];
    int slot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if (playerNames[i] != "-"){
            if (i == slot){
                sorted[slot] = playerNames[i];
            }
            else {
                sorted[i] = playerNames[i];
            }
            slot++;
        }
        else if (playerNames[i] == "-"){
            slot++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if (wcslen((WCHAR*)sorted[i]) < 3){
            sorted[i] = "<Unknown>";
        }
        playerNames[i] = sorted[i];
    }
}
```

This should return

```
Player1
Player2
Player3
Player4
Player5
Player6
Player7
Player8
Player9
Player10
Player11
Player12
Player13
Player14
Player15
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
<Unknown>
```

EDIT: Tried the following, but I still don't get it to work:

```
void sort(){
    char* sorted[30];
    int slot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if (strcmp(playerNames[i], "-") != 0){
            if (i == slot){
                sorted[slot] = playerNames[i];
            }
            else {
                sorted[i] = playerNames[i];
            }
            slot++;
        }
        else if (playerNames[i] == "-"){
            slot++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if (strlen(sorted[i]) < 3){
            sorted[i] = "<Unknown>";
        }
        playerNames[i] = sorted[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not cast strings.

Comment: `if (playerNames[i] != "-"){` will *always* succeed. C-style strings aren't compared that way; you're comparing two different pointers for equality. What you want is `strcmp()` or the WCHAR variant.

Comment: Also: `i < 30` means you'll eventually be accessing `i[29]`, which does not exist (a 29-element array will have elements 0 through 28).

Comment: there is still `playerNames[i] == "-"`

Comment: Either tag your question as C, or start using C++ `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one problem: `if (playerNames[i] != "-"){` will never execute the `true` branch because you're performing a pointer comparison, not a value comparison (C++ is not like Javascript or C#). You're comparing the memory address of a string in `playerNames` with the address of the literal string `"-"`.

Also a few other points:

1. Don't use C-style casts in C++. Use the C++ casting operators (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` instead as needed).
2. As you're using C++, use the STL's string types instead of C-style strings, as they have built-in comparison features.
3. `playerNames` has 30 elements but `sorted` has 29 elements. Why is there a difference?
4. `sorted` has function scope lifetime. Once `sort` returns any pointer to `sorted` is invalid and the data will likely be overwritten by a subsequent function call or stack allocation.
5. Your code doesn't actually perform any sorting, it simply iterates through the list twice resulting in, what seems to me, are meaningless comparisons.

Comment: I made sorted a 30 elements array, also changed `if(playerNames[i] != "-")` to `if(strcmp(playerNames[i], "-") != 0)`. Still dosen't work

Comment: `playerNames[i] != "-"` would work if strings in that array were actually C++ strings, not C strings.

Comment: @Hx0 Honestly, just load your strings into a `std::vector<string>` and call `std::sort` on the vector and you're done.

Comment: I can't, I'm using an API and most functions returns Any* , I tried to do my code with string and with vector and I always end up with player names in digits.

Comment: @Hx0 none of that sounds like a reason you can't use the STL.